# erros with torch.load when doing distributed training

Tags: python, pytorch

when i use `torch.load` to load a dataset, error occurs(i use 4 gpus and one machine for distributed training),

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Run.py", line 437, in <module>
    ready_train()
  File "Run.py", line 288, in ready_train
    train_ae(aemodel)
  File "Run.py", line 125, in train_ae
    'nlp_chinese_corpus'])
  File "Run.py", line 51, in read_json
    samples = torch.load(slpath + dir + ".pkl")  # 加载一个数据集下的数据
  File "/home_ex/tianhongtao/SW/anaconda3/envs/Hisense/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 526, in load
    if _is_zipfile(opened_file):
  File "/home_ex/tianhongtao/SW/anaconda3/envs/Hisense/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 76, in _is_zipfile
    if ord(magic_byte) != ord(read_byte):
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
```

how would i do?

Comment: Hi Kaim hong, probably your data is corrupt. Anyway, can you provide a small code snippet to see where the error occurs?

Comment: Hi, Guillem. Thanks for the suggestion, I slightly modified the way of loading data and now the error has not occured. Thanks again.